# LEFT JOIN (mysql)

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to left joing?

Left table

```
SELECT TYPE , days
FROM leavetypes


type  days  
anual   10

casual  6

sick    10
```

right table

```
SELECT sub_leave_type, (
SUM( working_days )
) AS used
FROM vacations
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
AND `from_date`
BETWEEN '2012-01-01'
AND '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY sub_leave_type


sub_leave_type      used

anual               3

casual              6
```

actually I am doing this on cakephp this is my code.

```
$allleaves = $this->Leavetype->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'vacations',
                'alias' => 'vacationsJoin',
                'type' => 'left',
                'conditions' => array('vacationsJoin.sub_leave_type = Leavetype.type')
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'vacationsJoin.user_id' => $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'],
            'vacationsJoin.from_date  BETWEEN ? and ?' => array(date('Y') . '-01-01',
                date('Y') . '-12-31')
        ),
        'fields' => array('type', 'days', '(SUM(working_days)) as used'),
        'group' => 'sub_leave_type',
            ));

    $this->set(compact('allleaves'));
```

This not out out that what i want, I want is all the row of left table and others from vacations table

Comment: What exactly do you need? How do you need to join those tables? What did you try and what didn't work? LEFT JOIN is the same in MySQL as in most other SQL dialects, you can just write it like you're used to and it should work.

Comment: You can answer your own question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was correct the problem here is the answer. main problem was in GROUP

```
$allleaves = $this->Leavetype->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'vacations',
                'alias' => 'vacationsJoin',
                'type' => 'left',
                'conditions' => array('vacationsJoin.sub_leave_type = Leavetype.type',
                     'vacationsJoin.user_id' => $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'],
            'vacationsJoin.from_date  BETWEEN ? and ?' => array(date('Y') . '-01-01',
                date('Y') . '-12-31'),'vacationsJoin.status'=>'approved'
                    )
            )
        ),

        'fields' => array('type', 'days', '(SUM(working_days)) as used'),
        'group' => 'type'
            ));
    $this->set(compact('allleaves'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Please read this query and change it according to your requirement

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
LEFT JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```